# How to check that a mapping transforming a nowhere dense set to a null set is a homeomorphism?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

In "Measure and Category" by Oxtoby there is a chapter devoted to transforming subsets of the real line into null sets.

Let $m$ denote the Lebesgue measure on the real line. Let $F\subset \mathbb [0,1]$ be a closed and nowhere dense set. Denote $G:=[0,1]\setminus F$. Finally, for every $x\in [0,1]$, let

$$h(x)=\frac{m([0,x]\cap G)}{m(G)}.$$

I need to show that $h$ is a homeomorphism of $[0,1]$ onto itself such that $h(F)$ is null.

I have done most of the proof- **the only part lacking is showing that $h$ is "onto".** I know it must have something to do with the fact that $G$ is dense and open but cannot get to the bottom of it. Can you please help me with this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't it enough to note that $h(0)=0$ and $h(1)=1$ when $h$ is continuous ?
The intermediate value theorem (connectedness, basically) implies surjectivity of $h$. And compactness that $h$ is a homeomorphism, if $h$ is 1-1 too.

Comment: Of course, you are right! Now I can't believe I hadn't thought about it... Thanks ;)